# What are the costs involved in triggering functions in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I am interested in triggering notifications into my Salesforce system when reviews are posted on my Google Business profile.

Using [this article](https://medium.com/the-innovation/salesforce-subscription-to-google-pub-sub-topic-using-google-cloud-functions-secret-manager-and-29f3c290f1a6), it describes being able to call the Salesforce API by executing Python code using Google's App Engine, leaving very little for me to code myself but I'm not familiar with how Google works in terms of billing.

Essentially when a topic/subscription is triggered, Google will execute a small python script to call the Salesforce API. I want to know how much will it cost to do this, or how can I calculate how this will be billed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be referring to Cloud Functions because that's the product used in the article (also, Cloud Functions has Pub/Sub event trigger). App Engine and Cloud Functions are both serverless products but they have different use cases. If you wish to know the difference between them, here's a [good SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47060993/7031308).

You are billed depending on how long the function takes to finish, how many times you invoke it, and the type of resources configured on the function (the higher the CPU & memory is, the higher the cost). There's additional charges as well if your function makes outbound data transfer whenever you invoke the function.

You can estimate your monthly cost by checking out [GCP pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). Also, there are several products involved on the article (such as Secret Manager and Pub/Sub) so take note of adding these products on your estimate. For additional pricing details, check out the docs: https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing

I also have another advice though this is not about the pricing when invoking the function but more of the additional when deploying it. From [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building#changes_to_your_project):

> When you deploy your function's source code to Cloud Functions, that source is stored in a Cloud Storage bucket. Cloud Build then automatically builds your code into a container image and pushes that image to Container Registry. Cloud Functions accesses this image when it needs to run the container to execute your function.

This apply on newer runtimes. It may be noticeable on your billing if you frequently deploy/update a function because Cloud Build has to re-build those images and those images has to be stored on a Cloud Storage bucket. Functions take time to deploy so it's best practice to test your functions first locally. A solution is to use [Functions Framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework).